# Dart - pub get fault

Tags: dart, dart-pub

The following pubscec.yam file appears puts the "pub get" application into an endless loop.

Windows, dart 1.11.0
Should I raise a fault?

```
name: epd_api_shelf
version: 0.0.1
description: A minimal web server using the shelf package.
environment:
  sdk: '>=1.9.0 <2.0.0'
dependencies:
  html: any
  http: any
  intl: any
  jsonx: any
  logging: any
##  pool: any
##  quiver: any
##  quiver_log: any
  rpc: any
  shelf_route: any
dev_dependencies:
  mock: any
  test: any
  http_server: any
dependency_overrides:
  quiver: '>=0.21.3'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not endless, just there is hard to resolve dependencies appeared, causing long time to solve them. For me, this file says the following:

```
Package matcher has no versions that match ^0.12.0-alpha.0 derived from:
- quiver 0.21.3 depends on version >=0.10.0 <0.12.0
- test 0.12.0-beta.2 depends on version ^0.12.0-alpha.0
```

Looks like `rpc` package have very old dependencies declared, causing constraints to be so tight. Commenting out this package makes all dependencies resolved just fine.

So you have two ways to solve this problem:

1. Ask `rpc` package maintainer to bump dependencies version and publish it. This is easiest solution for you, but can take time if maintainer is busy.
2. Fetch it's repo, upgrade dependencies by yourself, run all tests, put override in your dependencies to check everything works, and then provide pull request to maintainer. This will require more deep knowledge in Dart, but probably will be faster.

Choose what is better for you.